# To embed youtube video in ionic2 app

Tags: youtube, ionic2

I want to embed Youtube videos in my ionic2 app I have used Youtube pipe and imported following:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

the youtube.ts contain following

```
   constructor(private dom: DomSanitizer) {


    }

  transform(value, args) {
    return this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
}
}
```

Also I have imported it in app.module.ts like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
...
import{ YoutubePipe } from '../pipes/youtube/youtube';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ...
    YoutubePipe
  ],
```

In my .html file I have written this:

```
 <iframe width="560" Cannot GET /uri.vurl%20%7C%20youtube
height="315" src="uri.vurl | youtube" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It giving me like this on the output screen:

**Cannot GET /uri.vurl%20%7C%20youtube**

What should I do anyone please help.

Comment: Why did you put `Cannot GET /uri.vurl%20%7C%20youtube` in your `ifram` tag in `.html`??

Comment: try `src="{{uri.vurl | youtube}}"`

Comment: **Cannot GET /uri.vurl%20%7C%20youtube**  is showing in output and i have tried this `src="{{uri.vurl | youtube}}"` but its not working

Comment: in console it is showing this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: can anyone plz give soluion?

Comment: You likely will get a better answer if you update and fix your question first. Currently, it shows you have `Cannot GET /uri.vurl%20%7C%20youtube` in your iframe tag, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import **DomSanitizer** in your **.ts** file like this:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Next, declare a variable in your constructor

```
constructor(..., private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
```

If you are display a single video which you already have the uri, you can declare an instance variable and pass in the uri like this:

```
this.videoUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://....")
```

Now, in your **.html** file, do this:

```
<iframe [src]="videoUrl" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="155" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Hope this helps.